# How to get body of a function using redbaron library

Tags: python, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to extract root functions from a python script for splitting them to a separate files. I have to keep original formatting, comments, ets, therefor standard `ast`/`astunparse` modules doesn't work for me.

I found out great python library [redbaron](https://redbaron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is very powerfull and flexible. Unfortunately I don't know how to extract function body only.
Here is what I've tried so far:

```
tree = redbaron.RedBaron(code_source)
functions = tree.find_all('DefNode')
for fn in functions:
  if fn.indentation != '':
    # only interested in root functions
    continue

  with open('/tmp/%s.py' % fn.name, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(fn.dumps())
```

For a simple input like this:

```
def foo():
  if True:
    do_something()
```

it produces exactly the same output (expected behaviour). What I want is to extract only the function body, without name and parameters and correctly indented:

```
if True:
  do_something()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what if you just loop over the lines and look for those that start with `def ` ?

Comment: The problem not only in removing function name, but also correctly indenting rest of the code. This could probably done with string replacement, but it's not very reliable approach, e.g. it won't work on multiline dosctrings. Probably there is a better way, but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: May I ask what did you end-up doing?

Comment: I found better alternative LibCST: https://libcst.readthedocs.io